# Is there a Solace equivalent to ActiveMQ virtual topics?

Tags: jms, solace, virtual-topic

Is there a Solace equivalent to ActiveMQ's virtual topics?

Suppose you have two different components each consuming from the same Solace queue - component1 and component2.  Suppose both are load balanced, giving you component1_instance1, component1_instance2, component2_instance1, and component2_instance2.

Can Solace be set up so that each message in the Solace queue is consumed by:

- one and only one instance from component1 AND
- one and only one instance from component2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solace has a concept of "Topic Subscription on Queues" (see https://solace.com/blog/topic-subscription-queues/). You could setup a topic "Topic1" and have 2 queues (Q1 and Q2) configured to subscribe from this topic.

Each message you send on Topic1 is automatically put into Q1 and Q2. Your component1 instances could then consume from Q1 and component2 instances consume from Q2.